# C# i use Modbus/TCP to get Data, Data type is 「LReal」. i want turn to double

Tags: c#, types, modbus

i use Modbus/TCP to get data, data type is  LReal.

but i want LReal to int.

this is my data.

[image]

[image]

[image]

staic_13 data is 「4.232」

but i get  [80] 16400  [81]-2098 [82] -9962 [83] -30933.

i don't know how turn to double

Comment: So, if the value of _static\_14_ is 4.232, you want in the end to get an int with the value `4`; do i understand you correctly?

Comment: i want get 4232 for int  or 4.232 for double

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately your question doesn't mention any of this business with the int value being an entirely different value from the lreal/double (i mean, the desired int is 1000x larger than the lreal/double value). Either strip the mention of `int` from your question, or let the question explain how _exactly_ the `int` value should be retrieved from the lreal/double value.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace 4.232 was a typo, it should be 4.242. Anyway, see my answer: the trick is to interpret the 4 16-bit values as 1 double.

Comment: @AKX, the point of my comments was not about the specific value of the real number, but rather about the real number vs. integer number dissonance in both the original version of the question -- which has been fortunately edited in the meantime -- and OP's comment. As such, my comments did not deal nor were concerned with obtaining the actual real number value, only with the fact the source value _is_ a real number and not an integer number OP seemed to have wanted in the former original question...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Well, the original title had "turn to int or double". From "LReal" it's clear the original data is a real number, i.e. not an int.

Comment: @AKX, no, the original first version title and question body spoke only about getting an LReal value as int and didn't mention double at all. Check the history of the question. I know that LReal is a real number, jeez. LReal not being an int was the whole point of my original comments. It was very suspicious that OP wanted to end up with an int and not with a float/double in the original version of the question.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I missed the original-original title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this experimental Python code,

```
>>> x = [16400, -2098, -9962, -30933]
>>> struct.unpack(">d", struct.pack(">4h", *x))
(4.242,)
```

it looks like you'd need to concatenate those 4 16-byte integers in big-endian format, then interpret those 8 bytes as a single big-endian `double`.

In .NET 6 (see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pPeMs5)):

```
using System.Buffers.Binary;
using System;

short[] values = {16400, -2098, -9962, -30933};
byte[] buf = new byte[values.Length * sizeof(short)];
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt16BigEndian(buf.AsSpan(i * sizeof(short)), values[i]);
}
double result = BinaryPrimitives.ReadDoubleBigEndian(buf);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

In .NET 4 (see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T2lHLO)):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        short[] values = {16400, -2098, -9962, -30933};
        byte[] buf = new byte[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            byte[] sh_buf = BitConverter.GetBytes(values[i]);
            if(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
                // Flip the bytes around if we're little-endian
                buf[(3 - i) * 2] = sh_buf[0];
                buf[(3 - i) * 2 + 1] = sh_buf[1];
            } else {
                buf[i * 2] = sh_buf[0];
                buf[i * 2 + 1] = sh_buf[1];
            }
        }
        double result = BitConverter.ToDouble(buf, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry  my  .Net is 4.6.1.  so i don't have System.Buffers.Binary;

Comment: you have another method ? thx

Comment: @jacklee Added a .NET 4 version. It's a bit more complex.

Comment: thx you, i get  data .   love you